# how to explain some part of this code?

Tags: java

this code is test if two input are anagram which is from an answer of stackoverflow which can solve my problem but I don't understand some part of it. I believe that I will learn nothing if I am not totally understand it.

```
    public static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2){
    //case insensitive anagram

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s2.toLowerCase());
    for (char c: s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
        if (Character.isLetter(c)){

            int index = sb.indexOf(String.valueOf(c));
            if (index == -1){
                //char does not exist in other s2
                return false;
            }
            sb.deleteCharAt(index);
        }
    }
    for (char c: sb.toString().toCharArray()){
        //only allow whitespace as left overs
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

1. `int index = sb.indexOf(String.valueOf(c));` what does this means? normally `indexOf()` there is a number in it. does `String.valueOf(c)` return a number?
2. `if (!Character.isWhitespace(c))` why there is ! before Character? whats that for?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? All the methods in the standard API are documented.

Comment: It does look innecessarily wordy to test if two strings are anagrams of one another...

Comment: I believe you will learn very little unless you actually run it under debugger and see for yourself.

Comment: indexOf(string) returns index of string, "!" means "not"

Comment: Do you know how to use the Javadocs to find out what various methods do, such as `String.valueOf`, `StringBuffer#indexOf` and `Character.isWhitespace`?  That would be the most valuable thing for you to learn at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I documented your method, you should understand everything now :

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
    //Create a string buffer of the second string as lower case.
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s2.toLowerCase());
    /*
     * Convert all characters of the first string to lowercase.
     * Split the string into an array of char
     * Loop over all chars, the current char is accessible by the variable c.
    */
    for (char c : s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        //Character functionallity to check if the current character is a letter
        if (Character.isLetter(c))
        {
            //Retrieve the index of the current char in the second string, -1 will be returned if not found
            int index = sb.indexOf(String.valueOf(c));

            //if not found, we return false.
            if (index == -1) {                    
                return false;
            }

            //Remove the current char from the second string.
            sb.deleteCharAt(index);
        }
    }

    //Loop over all characters of the second string (you should understand this as it is the same logic as the first loop).
    for (char c : sb.toString().toCharArray()) {
        //only allow whitespace as left overs
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            //return false if something else then a whitespace is found
            return false;
        }
    }

    //If we arrive here it means that the algorithm was not able to prove false so we return true.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: why char c have to present as string likeString.valueOf(c); ?instead of sb.indexOf((c));?

Comment: @users1141df  `StringBuffer` does not have an indexOf method that receive a Char as parameter, this is why we have to convert to string.

Comment: so StringBuffer can only use method .append?

Comment: No, StringBuffer contains many methods. However, it does not contain a method indexOf that receive a Char as parameters. You can find all the methods of StringBuffer in the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Comment: why s1 and s2 have to become chararray?

Comment: why s2 is stringbuffer? can they both is stringbuffer?

Comment: @users1141df They could both be stringbuffer. However there would be no point in this case. StringBuffer is used here for memory concern.

Comment: s1 and s2 are charArray so it is easier to loop over all characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sb.indexOf()` takes a string as a parameter and returns the location in `sb` where that string is located, or -1 if it is not present.
2. The `!` means not. So the if statement is saying: if c is not a whitespace character, then do something.

Comment: thanks that solve my problem there is an another one i just foudn why it it deleted the character at index? sb.deleteCharAt(index);

Comment: It deletes it so that when it processes through the second string it will have no characters to compare.